# Why EXPO standalone app shows url_invalid?

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments, strip

i am working with Expo project using [stripe react native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native) , its work fine in local, publish but not working as expected in standalone app,

here i use stripe for payment and when i enter card info its returns  erorr 400

```
400 Error
POST /v1/payment_intents/pi_3JSeHwSJwGztdZyL1BuqSJQq/confirm
"return_url": "myappname:///--/://safepay",
url_invalid - return_url Not a valid URL
```

here is my code :

```
            <StripeProvider
            publishableKey="xyz"
            urlScheme={Linking.createURL('') + '/--/'}
            setUrlSchemeOnAndroid = {true}
            .............................../>
```

```
 const handleDeepLink = useCallback(
      async (url: string | null) => {
        if (url && url.includes('safepay')) {
          await handleURLCallback(url);
          console.log('url',url)
          navigation.navigate('Checkout', { url });
        }
      },
      [navigation, handleURLCallback]
    );




  useEffect(() => {
    const getUrlAsync = async () => {
      const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      handleDeepLink(initialUrl);
      console.log('initialUrl',initialUrl)
    };

    const urlCallback = (event: { url: string }) => {
      handleDeepLink(event.url);
    };

    getUrlAsync();

    Linking.addEventListener('url', urlCallback);

    return () => Linking.removeEventListener('url', urlCallback);
  }, [handleDeepLink]);
```

how to achive deep link and how to resole this ?

Using:  Standalone app, **Expo 42, stripe-react-native :0.1.4**

Comment: myappname:///--/://safepay is not a valid URL(that's not specific to Stripe, it's just not a URL). I don't know why you're doing `+ '/--/'` in your scheme.

Comment: [Officel Ref LInk](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-payment/pull/193/files#diff-14f2faf1e4844e7e9e5bcbb71bea64e1dd27d9c09f0a05aa6d02fec208f9173a) i following this link

Comment: I think Karli is right. Ad a test you can try specifying the return url with http://something.more.normal and the error will probably go away... But exactly what to replace it with I forget. Maybe an exp proxy or something that can represent your deep link url as a normal url.